# Dual boot 12.04 and XP

Tags: dual-boot

I installed 12.04 alongside XP and when I restart it says ubuntu is not there and ONLY choice I have is XP without booting from CD for demo, I reinstalled thinking I missed somthing but no luck.  What am I missing??  Thanks

Think I found it I did not remember this machine had 2 HD's and it put it on the 2nd one.

But now that I took out 2nd drive it will only let me replace XP not install along side.

Tom H.

Comment: Are you using the default OS loader? Have you installed [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)?

Comment: By "it", do you mean GRUB or the standard XP boot screen?

Comment: I have the demo CD of 12.04 thats what I am installing from and it did not say anything about GRUB just asked if I wanted to install alongside XP.  I checked the GRUB menu.lst and it is non existant.

Comment: as for "it" that was in reference to the problem of why it would not boot but now it won't even let e try and install along side it.  So still on the learning curve thanks Evandro and Marty.